# "right" never changes the vertical alignment?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to put a font awesome to the **bottom right** corner of an another font awesome icon.
I've come up with the following:

```
 <span class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i style="color:red;" class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-1x text-danger overlay-lower-right"></i>
</span>

.overlay-lower-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -20px;
}
```

However apparently no matter what I put as the **right** value the icon ALWAYS stays horizontally centered.
Only when I input **left** it changes.

What's the problem here? All I'm trying to do is to position the icon all the way to the right.

Here's a jsFiddle with the code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yjh0a23w/1/

Comment: What is the css for `fa-stack`? If your span has no width then it will probably only be as big as the icon you are using. e.g. you give `fa-stack` a width of 600px then your css above would move the icon

Comment: I don't know what is the issue, but if you just want to position the icon to the right, why not just use `text-align: right;`?

Comment: @haxtbh
I tried setting the span width to 600 - it doesn't move the icon to the right as expected.

Comment: @LéoLam
Well that works so thanks. However I'd like to know why the "right" attribute doesn't work for this example (for the learning purposes).

Comment: I see! Don't forget to accept an answer (in 2 days) if you got your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `font-awesome.css` you set `left: 0` for `.fa-stack-1x`.

To fix that, you have to reset `left` using `left: auto;` and then set `right` position.

```
.overlay-lower-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -20px;
    left: auto; /* this line reset left: 0; */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjh0a23w/2/

Comment: Ahh I see. I has no idea! Thanks so much - it all makes sense now!